# How to make my boostrap 5 navbar collapse and stay closed?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, bootstrap-5

My Bootstrap 5 navbar will not stay closed. It immediately pops back open.

I have this navbar for my company site I am building, and I have been following all of the tutorials and looked at tons of stack overflow and stack exchange forums on the issue and my navbar is still snapping back open immediately upon closing. I have the imports correct, I've quadruple checked. I stripped all styling from it to try and get it to work, so no CSS needs to be included as the issue is consistent regardless of styling. I am using EJS with NodeJS and Express.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg">
    <a class="navbar-brand title" href="/"><img src="white_logo.png" style="max-width: 60px;"> NJC Studios</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="container collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="margin-right: 30px;">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <% if (title == 'About') { %>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/about" style="background-color: rgb(134, 168, 181);">About</a>
                <% } else { %>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
                <% } %>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <% if (title == 'Services') { %>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/services" style="background-color: rgb(134, 168, 181);">Services</a>
                <% } else { %>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/services">Services</a>
                <% } %>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ">
                <% if (title == 'Learn') { %>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/learn" style="background-color: rgb(134, 168, 181);">Learn</a>
                <% } else { %>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/learn">Learn</a>
                <% } %>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <% if (title == 'Portfolio') { %>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/portfolio" style="background-color: rgb(134, 168, 181);">Portfolio</a>
                <% } else { %>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                <% } %>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ">
                <% if (title == 'Contact') { %>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/contact" style="background-color: rgb(134, 168, 181);">Contact</a>
                <% } else { %>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
                <% } %>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens that the *container* class appears together with *collapse* and *navbar-collapse*. If you check the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navbar), you will see that in the example they provide, the class *container-fluid* appears inside a `div` that wraps all the navbar content. Adding that `div`, it would look like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand title" href="/"><img src="white_logo.png" style="max-width: 60px;"> NJC Studios</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="margin-right: 30px;">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/services">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/learn">Learn</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And replacing *container* with *container-fluid*, it would look like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand title" href="/"><img src="white_logo.png" style="max-width: 60px;"> NJC Studios</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="margin-right: 30px;">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/services">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/learn">Learn</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

You have to pay a lot of attention when "building" a navbar (both with HTML and CSS), as it depends on this that the animations work correctly.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thank you so much. I have never sat down and read through the docs thoroughly and really only have a super high level understanding of each class. I will be more diligent and do some more research in the documentation moving forward. Much appreciation!